# make button clickable after checking two check boxes in android

Tags: android, button, checkbox, clickable

how can i make button clickable after checking two check boxes in android

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ok1" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ok2" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start" />
```

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    final CheckBox ch1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
    final CheckBox ch2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
    final Button start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    if(ch1.isChecked() && ch2.isChecked()){
        start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

i am new to programming

thanks in advance

Comment: Show your code: what you tried and where you got stuck. This will increase the chances you get an answer and reduce the chances of down voting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Button.setEnabled(Boolean)` to control if the button is clickable or not. Then create an `OnCheckedChangeListener` for the checkboxes. These are used to react to a change in the `checkboxes`. Within the listener, check if the `checkboxes` are both checked. If they are, enable the button. Otherwise, if the button is enabled, disable it.

Also, enabling and disabling the button will cause it to be grey when disabled. You can also use `setClickable` if you do not want an appearance change for the button

```
final Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
b.setEnabled(false);
final CheckBox cb1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
final CheckBox cb2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
OnCheckedChangeListener checker = new OnCheckedChangeListener(){ 

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton cb, boolean b) {
        if(cb1.isChecked()&&cb2.isChecked()){
            b.setEnabled(true);
        }
        else if(b.isEnabled()){
            b.setEnabled(false);
        }

    }

};
cb1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checker);
cb2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checker);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "It Worked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

});
```